# Spaces in ActiveMQ AuthorizationEntry Group Names

Tags: authorization, activemq-classic, spaces, jaas, active-directory-group

I am trying to use the JaasAuthenticationPlugin to authenticate users trying to access specific queues. (Most of my code is based off of the examples given in ActiveMQ in Action)

Ultimately, I want to authenticate against an Active Directory server, which may have groups with spaces in their names, but when I attempt to use groups with spaces in their names, I run into problems. What I have so far:

login.config:

```
activemq-domain {
org.apache.activemq.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
    debug=true
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="users.properties"
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.group="groups.properties";
};
```

users.properties:

```
user=password
```

group.properties:

```
users=user
Users Group=user
```

activemq.xml:

```
    <plugins>   
        <jaasAuthenticationPlugin configuration="activemq-domain" />
        <authorizationPlugin>
            <map>
            <authorizationMap>
                <authorizationEntries>
                    <authorizationEntry queue=">"
                                            read="users"
                                            write="users"
                                            admin="users" />
                <authorizationEntry topic=">"
                                            read="users"
                                            write="users"
                                            admin="users" />                                            

                </authorizationEntries>
            </authorizationMap>
            </map>
        </authorizationPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

This works fine, but as soon as I try to use "Users Group" instead of "users", I get:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: User user is not authorized to create: topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.Connection
```

Are group names with spaces unsupported by ActiveMQ or JAAS? Do I need to escape the spaces somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the space

Change:

```
Users Group=user
```

To:

```
Users\ Group=user
```